# How can I receive data (file.txt) from my iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, copy

In my App, I am creating a file.txt with some data.
The path of the file is:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];
```

How can I programatically copy or send that file to my computer?
After my program is done how can I copy that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your info.plist set "Application supports iTunes file sharing" to YES.

Then you save your files in documents folder via iTunes. Click your device -> apps -> your app

Answer (score 0):

If you have Dropbox installed on phone and PC you can use the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) to write files from your App to a drive accessible on your PC.

Comment: but how can i create my file in a dropbox folder? or move my file from NSDocumentDirectory to dropbox folder ?

Comment: Use the Dropbox SDK - check out the [tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/setup#ios).